# Filemaker Pro field jump on duplication

Tags: filemaker

I have a small more trivial type of question that is probably a no brainer:
   -  I’m working with a database that has consecutive numbers applied to a field.
   -  At some point the users have tried to “delete” records due to a jump in the value on duplication
   -  This error has compounded so that now, it’s up to jumping by 15 every time a record or set of records is duplicate
        -  So if it was 1 record, they’d have to manually adjust the field back by 15
        -  So say the record being duplicated is 100, 
   On duplication it would be 115
   It would be adjusted back by the user manually to 101
   Next time duplication of 101, it would duplicate to 116, and so on
   -  I tried creating a new empty version, and exported / imported values into a new file
        -  Same error exists in the new file

Where and how do I correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

If - as it seems - the field is auto-entering a serial number, you can set the next value to be generated by opening **File > Manage > Database**, selecting the field and clicking **Options…**.It will be under the **Auto-Enter** tab in the window that opens.
http://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fdefining-fields-manage-database.html%23

Another possibility is through the **Set Next Serial Value[]** script step.
http://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fset-next-serial-value.html%23

---

I am puzzled regarding the purpose of this field, if your users are allowed to modify it.